# connections such as USB and bluetooth randomly resets at once, and computer randomly powered off once

Tags: windows-10, usb, event-viewer

so i bought a new computer, and is in the process of moving the files. the problem is while the files are being moved from the usb drive to my computer, the progress bar randomly and frequently says there was an io error. when that happened, an explorer window opened showing my usb drive like i reconnected the device. at the same time, my bluetooth headphones said it disconnected from my computer and then reconnected. when i clicked 'try again', it worked for another few seconds, moved a few more files, before showing the error again. so i just pressed 'try again' again and again until i moved all my files. then i decided to look at the event viewer. there was a lot of errors. and then my computer powered off. not the normal shutting down screen, the screen just went black. and then it restarted. and this is what happened so far.

i am using a asus rog zephyrus g15 laptop, i updated bios before moving the files, and windows is latest version.

here's a screenshot of the event viewer:
[a screenshot of event viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFynn.png)

Comment: Contact the seller for support. This is either a hardware problem, or your computer needs new drivers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sometimes I've had issues with connection through a USB hub or extension cable timing out when transferring large files, while plugging the device directly into a USB socket works flawlessly... perhaps the cable or hub was of low quality.